# Pandas: Find keywords in excel rows of Column "summary" and if found write "PRI2" in the next column of the row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

For pandas: i am looking for some help to enhance the code below.

Currently, it has two excel files, one that has the 'summary' column and one that has the keywords. 
The code searches through the 'summary' column to see if it found any keywords, if found it prints 'PRI2' and which row the keyword was found.

I am trying to enhance it to write back to the excel sheet next to the 'summary' column with a new column  with the word "PRI2" at every corresponding rows when the keywords are found. Help please.

```
key = pd.read_excel('C:\\users\\Key.xlsx', sheet_name='PRI2')
testdata = pd.read_excel('C:\\users\\Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\users\\Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl')
testdata = testdata.dropna()


keywords = key["KeyW"].to_list()
testdata["keyword_search"] = -1


for index, row in testdata.iterrows()
checkstring = row["Summary"]

if (any(x in checkstring for x in keywords) == True):
     print("PRI2")
     print(f"Index:{index}")
```

Sample Data Set:

[image]

[image]

Desired Outcome:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide two small samples of the data so we know what you are working with?

Comment: Try `testdata.loc[testdata["keyword_search"].str.contains("|".join(key["KeyW"])), "Summary"] = "PRI2"`.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question with some sample data set and desired outcome

Comment: I tried @HenryYik and since it was not string i changed it to the below: `[testdata["keyword_search"].astype(str).str.contains("|".join(key["KeyW"])), "Summary"] = "PRI2"` but there was no change to the file or nothing was in the output